# How to create collection object in VBScript?

Tags: collections, vbscript

What should be the parameter for `CreateObject`?

See this example:

```
Dim a
Set a = CreateObject("Collection") 'getting a runtime error saying ActiveX 
' component can't create object: 'Collection
a.add(CreateObject("Collection"))
a.Items(0).Add(1)
MsgBox(a.Items(0).count)
MsgBox(a.Items(0).Item(0))
```

Comment: Usually you will import like this: CreateObject("library.class"). I guess you had missed one of the parts.

Comment: CreateObject("library.class") - in this which library & class we should provided? - we are lokking for these details..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

how about a Dictionary

```
Set coll = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
coll.Add 0, "5"
coll.Add 4, "10"
coll.Add "textkey", "15"
MsgBox coll.Count
MsgBox coll.Item(0)
MsgBox coll.Item(4)
wholeColl = ""
for each key in coll.Keys
  wholeColl = wholeColl & key & " = " & coll.Item(key) & ", "
next
MsgBox wholeColl
```

Answer (score 8):

**Here is the code, its powerful:**

```
Option Explicit

dim list
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
list.Add "Banana"
list.Add "Apple"
list.Add "Pear"

list.Sort
list.Reverse

wscript.echo list.Count                 ' --> 3
wscript.echo list.Item(0)               ' --> Pear
wscript.echo list.IndexOf("Apple", 0)   ' --> 2
wscript.echo join(list.ToArray(), ", ") ' --> Pear, Banana, Apple
```

Comment: This prompted me to install .NET, but on doing so it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

for:

```
dim lista : set lista = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

you can iterate like this:

```
dim key
for each key in lista.keys
    Wscript.Echo key & " = " & lista.item(key)
next
```

Comment: Merged into Tester101 answer