# How to loop through every word in a word document to modify the format of specific words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm struggling to find a way to loop through every word in a Word document and make the word bold if it's in a list of predefined words/terms. The predefined list is in  `strCollection`.

```
Sub BoldWords()

Dim strCollection(2) As String
    
strCollection(0) = "test"
strCollection(1) = "john"
strCollection(2) = "later"

For Each strWord In ActiveDocument.Words
    'If the strWord is in the strCollection
        'strWord.Font.BOLD = True
    'End If
Next strWord

End Sub
```

I can loop through the words okay, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the conditional logic to check if the word is in an array. I don't do a lot of VBA so I appreciate any help here.

I've looked at other answers to this question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711120/loop-through-each-word-in-a-word-document) but they don't run at all. Maybe they're for older versions of Word? I'm on O365.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38268261/8422953

Answer (score 2):

Looping through every Word in a document is terribly inefficient. You should instead consider using Find/Replace. For example:

```
Sub BoldWords()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ArrFnd As Variant, i As Long
'Array of Find expressions
ArrFnd = Array("test", "john", "later")
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Format = False
  .Forward = True
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .Replacement.Text = "^&"
  .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
   'Process each item from ArrFnd
  For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
    .Text = ArrFnd(i)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a nested loop to compare the word with each key in the collection, and then do stuff with it.  It also might be a matter of putting this code in the Document_Open() event handler so that it runs when the document is opened.

```vb
Private Sub Document_Open()

    Dim colCollection : Set colCollection = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim strWord, Key
        
    colCollection.Add 0, "test"
    colCollection.Add 1, "john"
    colCollection.Add 2, "later"

    For Each strWord In ActiveDocument.Words
        For Each Key in colCollection.Keys
            If strWord = colCollection.Item(Key) Then
                strWord.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

- Also see: [How to create collection object in vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864499/how-to-create-collection-object-in-vbscript)
- Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.open

Comment: This will not work as `strCollection` is an array and not a collection - although the variable name is pretending this ...

Comment: good catch, I rewrote it